# Segue moving too quickly while passing data?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uilabel, segue

I am making an app where the user inputs some numbers into a text field and it shoots out an answer on a label. I have the answer being displayed on another view controller. Using the same prepare for segue methods on all of the screens that I have only some of them work. The others will pass whatever text I have in the first view controller label (I have checked this by inputting all sorts of stuff and it shows up on the other side)... I have also deleted the segue and made sure that the calculation works and the label in the first view controller is getting the information.

This leads me to believe that the way it is set up is fine, but the segue happens so fast that the label on the first view controller will still have the original text when the segue is performed, sending that information over as a string instead of the answer...

Is it possible to change this? It would be the only logical thing that makes sense to me write at the moment. If it is possible how could this be fixed?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:

This is the whole code I was Asked To post to help figure this out

So if in the first view controller I put a '?' for the text in the label just to hold the label, and in the second view controller I put a '!' in the answer label to hold the label.. The second view controller after I run the simulator the second view controller will show a ? the text from the 1st label... so it does show that it is pushing the data over, it is just not pushing the information in the label.

Comment: probably should point out that I am writing in swift... not an expert just someone who does it as a hobby

Comment: Solution seems simple using the calculated value in prepareforsegue() before the segue happens but you can Show some code for getting the reason and making as understand the problem better.I have seen the tag core data are you in some way trying to store value in core data and getting from other view controller.

Comment: added some of the segue code so you can see..

Comment: So  you are saying that when you put a question mark inside the first label (in first view controller ) on performing the segue the question mark gets transferred to the second view controller label , right . so where is the problem what information you are saying is not transferred.

Comment: It is really hard for me to explain through writing although I will try. The question mark that gets passed is only used to make sure the segue works. The actual thing that should be passed during the segue is the answer that shows up in the label... EXAMPLE textfield 1 + textfield 2 = label1... when I run the simulator without the text segue the "label1" shows the answer of textfield1 + textfield2 although the holding (in my example a ?) text of the label is what is getting sent to the second view controller not the answer that is being displayed.... hope this makes sense

Comment: and no, core data was added as a tag because i was having these inconsistencies between view controllers (some working in passing some not using the same code) i was thinking that maybe I could use core data as a way to sure up some of the process... don't know a lot about core data just what I have read

Comment: What i Think is everything should run fine you have to make your calculations before sending the data , i.e. take whatever values from labels you want ,  you have to add them before sending in prepare for segue  . if you can show the whole controller code to me ,if you want to , it's a simple task you should not face any problem in this.

Comment: I will share, although I can tell you that if you delete the segue the calculations work and post correctly to the label I have set up in the first VC. I also add it in after the calculations. I use the prepare for segue as the last piece of code. I also have many different screens with different calculations and half of them work and half of them do this. It is a easy thing to do, it just doesn't seem to work consistently. I can copy and paste from one vc to another and change the outlets and one will work and one will send what ever the label says before a calculation gets pushed to it...

Comment: Well share the code I'm sure we will get a little more understanding of the issue

Comment: When I get home tonight I will share it to see what is going on... thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I have posted some sample code that you asked for... this does not work in my project it send what ever text I have in Label1 but does not show the total calculation (when you drag a label out the text show label, it will send that text and not the text that show up after the calculation) I have done this same code on 20 screens and 10 work and 10 dont, i am really confused... Somebody please help

Comment: So when are you performing the segue , is it same with IBOutlet action

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a made a segue to another view controller from the same button , with which you are performing the `@IBAction func usednroicalc(sender: AnyObject)`, what you have to do is make a segue from view controller to another view controller in storyboard , give your segue an identifier and inside the @IBAction  write at the place where you want to perform the segue , that is after your calculations write , `self.performseguewithIdentifier("your identifier")` . you can give identifier to segue by clicking on it and than find the identifier label in the inspector.
**EDIT:**
[image]

Here I have dragged from ViewController the one Highlighted as yellow in ViewController Scene to TableViewController the one above first responder in TableView Controller Scene.

Comment: I will take a look today and let you know if it fixes it.

Comment: I only have one segue to the VC I am sending it to. I put all the self.performseguewithIdentifier("My Identifier", sender:nil) and it still passes the same information. the label when unhidden just before segue does post the correct calculation answer but it doesn't get transferred to the second VC

Comment: I have tried everything to make this work... Should I just be doing this in NSUserDefualts and pass it that way? takes more code but I feel as if it would be more reliable

Comment: okay so I went through my outlets, and It did say that the button had something else attatched to it.. probably from copy pasting interface objects to different screens. I deleted all the outlets and actually deleted the button and re-set up a different button, and it still does the same thing

Comment: none of this is working. I am thinking considering I have rebuilt all the VC's that dont work and created new outlets and new segues that this information is not going to pass. I dont know if this is a swift error. 3/4 of the VC's work 1/4 dont using the same style and code. Maybe it is because I have a lot of different VC's (over 50) using this same technique I don't know.. I am chalking this up as a swift error and looking for new ways to make this consistent. anyone know if I can use nsuserdefaults or coredata to push the information to a new View controller?

Comment: the only thing that I havent tried, maybe someone could tell me if it would work or not is doing the calculation in the prepareforsegue and not in the button action

Comment: That would definitely work but the thing is the code self.performsegue should work , the only reason i can think of your  saying (Segue moving too quickly while passing data? ) is because you are putting an action and segue on same button . Have you tried my method putting calculation  inside your button and segue from view controller to view controller (no segue from button ) . last line after calculation should be self.performseguewithIdentifier("your identifier"). see the edit in the answer.

Comment: Yes, was doing it all last night.. it still sends what ever text is in the label and not what the calculation computes...

Comment: I am going to try the calculations in the performsegue function and see if I can get it to pass... if not I am going to again looking at databasing somehow or just creating a view that pops up over the current VC. I appreciate all your help trying to get this to work, i am sure you have better things to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to answer my own question as I have found a way to push the info over finally...

You have to set up the calculations of the code in the prepare for segue and not in the button action. The button action is now only setup for the segue to the new view controller. not the way I wanted everything thing to go but it works.

Thanks everyone for the feedback... hope this helps someone else in the future.